# json array sort by value in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, usort

I have JSON arrays of objects. I am trying to sort an array using usort. I want to use `value` field from `field_listing_order`. It sorted using value. I am missing something but not able to figure it out. please review the code. Thanks!

```
stdClass Object
(
    [node_title] => abc
    [nid] => 2281
    [field_api_order_value] => 201
    [field_node_entity_type] => node
    [_data] => Array
        (
            [nid] => Array
                (
                    [entity_type] => node
                    [entity] => stdClass Object
                        (

                            [title] => abc
                            [field_listing_order] => Array
                                (
                                    [und] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [value] => 8
                                                    [format] => 
                                                    [safe_value] => 8
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                       )

                 )

        )

)

stdClass Object
(
    [node_title] => abc
    [nid] => 2243
    [field_api_order_value] => 204
    [field_node_entity_type] => node
    [_data] => Array
        (
            [nid] => Array
                (
                    [entity_type] => node
                    [entity] => stdClass Object
                        (

                            [title] => abc
                            [field_listing_order] => Array
                                (
                                    [und] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [value] => 3
                                                    [format] => 
                                                    [safe_value] => 3
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                       )

                 )

        )

) stdClass Object
(
    [node_title] => abc
    [nid] => 2431
    [field_api_order_value] => 242
    [field_node_entity_type] => node
    [_data] => Array
        (
            [nid] => Array
                (
                    [entity_type] => node
                    [entity] => stdClass Object
                        (

                            [title] => abc
                            [field_listing_order] => Array
                                (
                                    [und] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [value] => 1
                                                    [format] => 
                                                    [safe_value] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                       )

                 )

        )

)
```

and So on ...

```
  foreach ($view->result as $result) {   
        $node = $result->_data['nid']['entity'];  
        $listing_order = $node->field_listing_order[LANGUAGE_NONE][0];
         .....            
       // code goes here and it works well. sorting issue
}

 usort ($node->field_listing_order[LANGUAGE_NONE][0], function($a, $b){
       return strcmp($a->value, $b->value);
   }); ?>
```

Comment: You want to sort elements inside `field_listing_order` or "global" objects?

Comment: It's about sorting global object using value not inside. $a and $b used comparing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to sort all the nodes using the `field_listing_order` value, you need to compare the values along the full path, from the first object to the value:

```
usort($view->result, function($a, $b) {
    $la = $a->_data['nid']['entity']->field_listing_order[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $lb = $b->_data['nid']['entity']->field_listing_order[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    return $la - $lb ;
});
```

In this case `$a` and `$b` are two different nodes which could be compared. That why you should compare the `field_listing_order`'s value of these nodes. The answer is working with `$la- $lb`

Comment: Note: this sort should be done outside the loop, of course.

Comment: it's not sorting and not seeing any error code either. What if the array is already sorted. Still we can sort using some other element. Right?

Comment: Yes, there is no changes if the array is already sorted. You could try `$la-$lb` to check if the order is reversed. Is it your question?

Comment: I am just asking. I will try `$la-$lb`.

Comment: Thank you @Syscall. Finally I have figured it out issue on my end and 
 it's working with  `$la-$lb `

Comment: Happy to hear that you've solved your issue! You're welcome @Nisarg :)